# PHP: Calling another public class method from another extended class file

Tags: php

how do I call a public class function from another extended class file, for this question is api.php. I want to be able to call `public function track_osc_delivery(){ }` in track.php from api.php class api extended rest. Please my code below, its been daunting to fix up, I tried including api.php into track.php but that did no good to solving it.

//rest.php

```
  class Rest {
    protected $request;
    protected $serviceName;
    protected $param;

    public function __construct(){
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST'){
            $this->throwError(REQUEST_METHOD_NOT_VALID, 'Request Method is not valid');
        }
        $handler = fopen('php://input', 'r');
        $this->request = stream_get_contents($handler); 
        $this->validateRequest();       
    }

        public function validateParameter($fieldName, $value, $dataType, $required = true){

        }

          public function processApi(){
        $api = new API;
        $rMethod = new reflectionMethod('API', $this->serviceName);
        if(!method_exists($api, $this->serviceName)){
           $this->throwError(API_DOST_NOT_EXIST, "API does not exist");
        }
        $rMethod->invoke($api);
    }
    }
```

//api.php

```
 class Api extends Rest {
public $dbConn;  

 public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();  
    $db = new DbConnect;
    $this->dbConn = $db->connect();

}


 public function track_osc_delivery(){

$waybill_number = $this->validateParameter('track_waybill_number', $this->param['track_waybill_number'], STRING, true);

$password_for_shipments = $this->validateParameter('track_password_sent', $this->param['track_password_sent'], STRING, true);

}
 }
```

//track.php

```
  require_once('functions.php');
   $api = new Api;
   $api->processApi();

   //WANT TO CALL public function track_osc_delivery() here
```

//functions.php

```
       spl_autoload_register(function($className){
         $path = strtolower($className) . ".php";
 if(file_exists($path)){
             require_once($path);
         } else {
             echo "File $path is not found.";
             exit();
         }
```

Comment: `$api->track_osc_delivery()`..?

Comment: @loek thanks, does that mean processAPi() is invalid

Comment: No? `processApi()` is inherited so you can just use it like you do.

Comment: Please keep your questions atomic and concise, this is another question entirely and one you've almost completely answered yourself. Create another question for this is you really run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand your question, i think this will be working via scope resolution operator and also via directly using $api->track_osc_delivery();
i have removed inner code of some of function to prevent errors.

(1) rest.php

```
<?php
class Rest {
    protected $request;
    protected $serviceName;
    protected $param;

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function validateParameter($fieldName, $value, $dataType, $required = true)
    { }

    public function processApi(){
        $api = new API;
        return $api;
    }
}

?>
```

(2) api.php

```
<?php
require_once('rest.php');
class Api extends Rest {
    public $dbConn;  

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  
    }


    public function track_osc_delivery(){
        return "function called";

    }
}

?>
```

(3)track.php

```
<?php
require_once('api.php');
$api = new Api;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($api);
echo "</pre>";
$api->processApi();

//echo $api->track_osc_delivery(); //this will also worked.
$test = $api::track_osc_delivery();
echo $test;
?>
```

feel free to ask regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work, in track.php, as Loek said it is inherited and as for process api it can also be included in the script

change code from

```
 require_once('functions.php');
 $api = new Api;
 $api->processApi();
```

to

```
  require_once('functions.php');
  $api = new Api;
  $api->track_osc_delivery();
```

Happy coding...